# get real size based on pixel size

Tags: android, opencv, size

I am trying to get the true object size in android app using **OpenCV** library.
I've created an app that is able to recognize a car (looking on it side). Now the thing that I need to do is too get it true width and height.

What I have:

I have the height and width in pixels of the object (I' wrapping the car in rectangle), I have the resolution of the camera that is used.

Can I convert in some way pixels to true size ? I can't use distance from me to object cause I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I convert in some way pixels to true size ? I can't use distance from me to object cause I don't know it

No, you can't without knowing the distance. The perspective projection of real world objects (the car) onto the 2D image plane results in an information loss. For example, take a small toy car near the camera and a normal car far from the camera. Both could result in the same projected size in pixels although their true sizes are different.

Comment: thanks, to be honest I was afraid of answer like that.Do you see any solution for my problem ? Or some kind of hint ? I diging this for couple of days and I'm not even a bit closer :(

Comment: If you are able to have a reliable reference object at the same distance as the car, e.g., ruler marks or even just a tire with known diameter, you could try to detect and measure this object's pixel size and calculate the car size based on that. However, this won't yield precise results anyway.